# Where can I find an MDX interpreter?

Tags: mdx, multidimensional-array

I want to learn some MultiDimensional eXpressions query language. I've already found sufficient theoretical information. Now, I want a place to write and test my own queries.

Where can I find an MDX interpreter? Either downloadable or available online?

Comment: Sorry, but [we don't serve shopping requests](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on SO.

Comment: Microsoft maintains samples here http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Saiku demo](http://demo.analytical-labs.com/) in MDX mode. It is loaded with the common Foodmart 2000 sample data warehouse which will give you a host of analytics scenarios to play with. This is an open source front-end to the open-sourced Mondrian OLAP engine.

To enable MDX mode, select a Cube from the dropdown and press the [image: MDX Mode] icon.